# Hibernate - IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to save LinkedList of QComputer using following code:

```
public void saveOrUpdateAll(Collection list) {
    final Session ses = getTxManager().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    list.stream().forEach((object) -> {
        ses.saveOrUpdate(object);
    });
    ses.flush();
}
```

and get an exception if variable **planServices** (table services_to_ip) in **QComputer** is not empty,  otherwise the data is stored in a table ip_to_unit:

```
[IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of ru.apertum.qsystem.server.model.QComputer.ip]
(org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of ru.apertum.qsystem.server.model.QComputer.ip)
SQL: 
    at ru.apertum.qsystem.client.forms.FAdmin.saveConfiguration(FAdmin.java:1910)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:662)
    at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:698)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.Event
```

DispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

1. QComputer.java (**ip_to_unit** table in mysql):

> ```
> public QComputer() { }
>
> private Long id;
>
> @Id
> @Column(name = "id")
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
> public Long getId() {
>     return id;
> }
>
> public void setId(Long id) {
>     this.id = id;
> }
>
> private String ip;
>
> public void setIp(String ip) {
>     this.ip = ip;
> }
>
> @Column(name = "ip")
> public String getIp() {
>     return ip;
> }
>
> private Integer unitId;
>
> public void setUnitId(Integer unitId) {
>     this.unitId = unitId;
> }
>
> @Column(name = "unit_id")
> public Integer getUnitId() {
>     return unitId;
> }
>
> private String name;
>
> public void setName(String name) {
>     this.name = name;
> }
>
> @Column(name = "name")
> public String getName() {
>     return name;
> }
>
> @Column(name = "deleted")
> @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
> private Date deleted;
>
> public Date getDeleted() {
>     return deleted;
> }
>
> public void setDeleted(Date deleted) {
>     this.deleted = deleted;
> }
>
> private List<QPlanService> planServices = new ArrayList<>();
>
> public void setPlanServices(List<QPlanService> planServices) {
>     this.planServices = planServices;
> }
>
> @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
> @JoinColumn(name = "ip", insertable = true, nullable = false, updatable = true, referencedColumnName="ip")
> @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
> public List<QPlanService> getPlanServices() {
>     return planServices;
> }
> ```

[image: ip_to_unit table]

2. QPlanService.java (**services_to_ip** table in mysql):

> ```
> public QPlanService() {}
>
> private Long id;
>
> @Id
> @Column(name = "id")
> @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
> public Long getId() {
>       return id;
> }
>
> public void setId(Long id) {
>       this.id = id;
> }
>
> private QService service;
>
> @OneToOne(targetEntity = QService.class)
> public QService getService() {
>       return service;
> }
>
> public void setService(QService service) {
>       this.service = service;
> }
>
> private String ip;
>
> @Column(name = "ip", insertable = false, updatable = false)
> public String getIp() {
>       return ip;
> }
>
> public void setIp(String ip) {
>       this.ip = ip;
> }
> ```

[image: services_to_ip table]

Why does this error occur? I think the solution to the problem is simple, but I could not understand the reason. Any help would be good.

Comment: You can not use ip as join column

Comment: I can't join by id, because i need to receive all rows from services_to_ip table with certain ip